# Explain why $\int_{\mathbb R^N}|\nabla u_r(x)|^p dx=r^p \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u(rx)|^p dx$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, estimation

Suppose
$$
(*) \quad \|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R^N})} \le c \|\nabla u\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R^N;\mathbb{R^N}})}.
$$
Assume $u\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and for $r>0$ defined the rescaled function
$$u_r(x) := u(rx), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N.$$

If $(*)$ holds for $u_r$ then
\begin{align}
\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u(rx)|^q dx\bigg)^{1/q} & = \bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u_r(x)|^q dx\bigg)^{1/q} \\
& \le c\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u_r(x)|^p dx\bigg)^{1/p} \\
& = c\bigg(r^p \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u(rx)|^p dx\bigg)^{1/p} \\
\end{align}

I don't see where the $r^p$ term is appearing from?

Comment: Keyword: Change of variable.

Comment: I dont see how change of variables gets used. By definition $u_r(x) = u(rx)$ so my attempt is $$c\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u_r(x)|^p dx\bigg)^{1/p} = c\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u(rx)|^p dx\bigg)^{1/p}.$$ What did I do wrong?

Comment: But $\nabla u_r(x)\ne\nabla u(rx)$... Why not come back to the basics when confused as you seem? In the present case, $u_r(x+h)-u_r(x)=u(rx+rh)-u(rx)\approx\nabla u(rx)\cdot(rh)=r\nabla u(rx)\cdot h$ for every $h$ hence...

Comment: @Did I don't see how you can just say $\nabla u_r(x) \neq \nabla u(rx)$. By definition $u_r(x) = u(rx)$, so if we take the gradient of both side we get precisely $\nabla u_r(x) = \nabla u(rx)$.

Comment: So... obviously you simply did not read my comment. Please note that the simple computation in it **disproves** your claim (except if $r=1$ or $\nabla u(rx)=0$, of course).

Comment: ((Oddly, you simultaneously accepted an answer stating that $\nabla u_r(x)\ne\nabla u(rx)$, and contested this very same statement in a comment. Please make up your mind...))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By Chain rule we have $\partial_i [u(rx) ]= r[\partial_i u](rx) .$ This yields

$$[\nabla u_r](x) =[\nabla u(\cdot r)](x)=r [\nabla u](rx)$$
Then integrates on both side.

Comment: This notation is a bit confusing..is the gradient with respect to $rx$ in the last item?